# Load data from datareader

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, database-schema

I want to read from my response data reader object the column name and type, because i need it to instantiate some objects. I came out with this :

```
using (db.sqlConnection) {
    db.sqlConnection.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("areaGetStreetTypes", db.sqlConnection)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)) {
            DataTable dt = dr.GetSchemaTable();
            foreach (DataRow myField in dt.Rows) {
                foreach (DataColumn coloana in dt.Columns) {
                    string c1 = coloana.ColumnName;  //column name ???
                    string c2 = coloana.GetType().ToString(); //column type ??
                    Console.WriteLine(c1 + "  " + c2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but is not working. For each column returns i want to print (for starter) something like :

```
id_someID int32    
name string    
surname string     
ssn string
```

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What is _"not working"_?

Comment: As you can see from the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.100).aspx GetSchemaTable returns a data set where each row holds the column data. You are listing the columns of that schema data set rather than the contents of the rows

Comment: how can i receive the data and the schema information in one query ? how can i access each one of them ?

Comment: Is the real question, how can I call a stored procedure and display the results when I don't know the schema of what it returns?

Comment: yes, i think that was my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually want somthing like

```
DataTable dt = dr.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataRow myField in dt.Rows) 
{
    var name = myField["ColumnName"];
    var type = myField["DataTypeName"];
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", name, type);
}
```

Comment: yes. that was the answer i was looking for, now i have to "convert" varchar to string.

Comment: @rhose87 there are lots of other columns in the schema set, check the link in my comment. There is one called `"DataType"` that contains a .Net type mapping

Comment: type = {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"} 

@Jodrell how can i get only "string" ?

Comment: @rhose87 `"{Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}"` is what the `Type.ToString()` returns for an instance of the .Net string type.

Answer (score 4):

No need to call GetSchemaTable to get datatype for each column because Reader already have all these details

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, sqlConn);
SqlDataReader sdr;
sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
{
    string dataTypeName = sdr.GetDataTypeName(i); // Gets the type of the specified column in SQL Server data type format
    string FullName = sdr.GetFieldType(i).FullName; // Gets the type of the specified column in .NET data type format
    string specificfullname = sdr.GetProviderSpecificFieldType(i).FullName; //Gets the type of the specified column in provider-specific format
    //Now print the values
}
```

Comment: schema table is a 0 based array ? how can i access the column name ?

Comment: @rhose87 `sdr.GetName(i)` would give you the column's name.

Comment: +1 for the info. But why do you discard the last column in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataColumn.DataType` property and `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly` enum member.

Comment: but i want to receive the data also.